# Is it an FERPA violation to hold a contest with a scoreboard, if the result will be used as part of the grade?

Tags: teaching

I am thinking of holding some Codeforces-style programming contest (e.g. https://codeforces.com/contest/1811) with a scoreboard (visible only to students) as part of the curriculum.

However, I wonder if there might be an argument that the scoreboard constitutes educational record (since the score relates to a part of the grade) and thus one student's performance cannot be visible to other students.

Is a score board more like peer grading (which is fine) or is it more like exam results (which is not fine)?

Comment: I suspect your local administration has the final say, so I'd start there.

Comment: I don't know anything about Codeforces or this scoreboard you reference, but my superficial first thought is to wonder whether basing a grade on this makes any sense at all.

Comment: You did not mention what country you are in. I'm going to guess that this may be different in different cultures. Different places may have quite different ideas about students knowing how other students are performing. So, as @JonCuster suggested, probably discuss with your admin.

Comment: What is your *goal* when assigning a grade to a student?  Is it to *sort* that student, relative to other students in the class?  or to indicate how well that student understands some body of material?  or...?

Comment: Your title mentions [FERPA](https://www2.ed.gov/policy/gen/guid/fpco/ferpa/index.html). Are you in the US?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can avoid issues by anonymizing the "scoreboard" so that true names and such are avoided. Give each participant/team a "name" known only to themselves. Now people can compare themselves to unknown others without revealing who those others are.

But the law is funny. I'd run this idea past administration before implementing it, but I'd guess it would pass muster.

I'd also guess that posting a list of grades without names is fine, just as publishing a grade distribution. The student knows their own grade, and the overall, but not the specifics for any other student.